# MySQL Fill with sample data (simple)

Tags: mysql

I'm completely new to MySQL, and was just wondering if someone could help me do something fairly simple to add sample data to my table.

I have a table, let's call it `table` and 5 columns, `id (int), name (varchar), desc, resp, comment (text)`

I just want to add sample data like this:

```
0   ABC-0000-0000  Lorem Ipsum... Lorem Ipsum... Lorem Ipsum...
1   ABC-0000-0001  Lorem Ipsum... Lorem Ipsum... Lorem Ipsum...
```

Etc

What's the command I have to use?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html

Comment: http://www.generatedata.com/

Answer (score 1):

I think 'desc' is a reserved word, so backtick your INSERT statement;

```
INSERT INTO `table` 
(`id`, `name`, `desc`, `resp`, `comment`) 
VALUES 
(0, "ABC-0000-0000", "Lorem Ipsum...", "Lorem Ipsum...", "Lorem Ipsum...")
```

or if the column ID has auto-increment;

```
INSERT INTO `table` 
(`name`, `desc`, `resp`, `comment`) 
VALUES 
("ABC-0000-0000", "Lorem Ipsum...", "Lorem Ipsum...", "Lorem Ipsum...")
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [**INSERT statement**](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp) like this:

```
INSERT INTO table (name , desc, resp, comment)
VALUES ("ABC-0000-0000", "Lorem Ipsum...", "Lorem Ipsum...","Lorem Ipsum...")
```

Note that ID (column) must be auto-increment and primary.

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is just import this data into a table, you could use the LOAD DATA statement.

Supposing the mentioned data is inside a file called "data.txt" (and the columns are separated by tabs), you could use the following command:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/path_to_the_file/data.txt' INTO TABLE table;
```